# Is AudioBufferSourceNode.start() broken in Chrome? Fails to start if offset parameter is provided

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-audio-api

My code works fine in FF however fails in Chromium Version 39.0.2171.65 on Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit).

Providing the `offset` parameter to `AudioBufferSourceNode.start(when, offset, duration)` causes no audio to play. Even if the offset is `0` which is apparently the default value.

The following plays audio successfully in both FF and Chrome:

```
AudioBufferSourceNode.start(0)
```

The following plays audio in FF, but fails without throwing any errors in Chrome

```
AudioBufferSourceNode.start(0, 0)
```

It seems that the source node never even starts at all. If I try and call `.stop()` I get the error

```
InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'stop' on 'AudioBufferSourceNode': cannot call stop without calling start first.
```

This post is mostly a sanity check to make sure I'm not crazy... likely a chrome bug? Here is the full code that is failing in Chrome:

```
  var audioCtx = this.audioCtx,
      audioSource = audioCtx.createBufferSource();

  var fileReader = new FileReader();

  fileReader.onload = function() {
    var arrayBuffer = this.result;

    audioCtx.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer, function(buffer) {
      audioSource.buffer = buffer;
      audioSource.connect(audioCtx.destination);
      audioSource.loop = false;
    }, function(e){ throw "Error with decoding audio data" + e.err;});

    audioSource.start(0, 0);
  };

  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(audioDataBlob);
```

Comment: Do you have any examples of your code? I have been using `start(0,0)` successfully in recent versions of FF and Chrome.

Comment: Well that's odd. What OS? I've updated my post with more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.start` should be within the `decodeAudioData` handler, you can only start once you setup the buffer:

```
audioCtx.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer, function(buffer) {
  audioSource.buffer = buffer;
  audioSource.connect(audioCtx.destination);
  audioSource.loop = false;
  audioSource.start(0, 0);
}, function(e){ throw "Error with decoding audio data" + e.err;});
```

Comment: Of course! That fixed it, thanks! But I'm not sure why it was partially working before? Particularly with the absence of the offset.